# Reading XML File Element and the value between

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio, xmlreader

I have searched and just cant find what I'm looking for...
I want to get all the elements and display (if it has) the content in the tag ?

example xml tag:

```
<username>pavle_stoj</username>
```

output in console:

```
username : pavle_stoj
```

I'm having trouble working it out ?

```
Imports System.Xml
Module Module1
    Sub Main()

    If IO.File.Exists("C:\Users\Pavle\Desktop\config.xml") Then
        Dim XmlReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create("C:\Users\Pavle\Desktop\config.xml")
        With XmlReader
            While .Read()
                If .NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element Then
                    If .IsStartElement() Then


                        Console.WriteLine("Element Name: " + .Name)
                        'Value Of Element: -> ???

                End If
            End While
        End With
        Console.Write(".. press any key ..")
        Console.ReadLine()
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("The filename you selected was not found.")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Module

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configfile>
 
<database_settings>
    <databasename>peopledb</databasename>
    <databaseuser>sa</databaseuser>
    <databasepassword>verysecurepassword</databasepassword>
</database_settings>
 
<domain_admin_settings>
    <username>myusername</username>
    <password>verysecurepassword</password>
    <domain>windowstest.local</domain>
</domain_admin_settings>
 
</configfile>
```

Comment: XmlReader.GetValueAsync might get you heading in the right direction https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.getvalueasync?view=net-5.0

Comment: @Hursey that doesn't address the OP actual issue. Pavle can you an example xml file so I can help you? In short, you can create objects that represent your data and then get anything you need.

Comment: i added the xml file here: https://pastebin.com/pFY6YkNm ... its nothing too flash, basic to parse info to the program - appended the post too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a test based on your description, and the following code works for me:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim path As String = "your xml path"
    If IO.File.Exists(path) Then
        Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(path)
            reader.MoveToContent()
            While reader.Read()
                If reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element Then
                    If reader.Name = "username" Then
                        Dim el As XElement = TryCast(XNode.ReadFrom(reader), XElement)
                        If el IsNot Nothing Then
                            Console.WriteLine(el.Value)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End While
        End Using

        Console.Write(".. press any key ..")
        Console.ReadLine()
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("The filename you selected was not found.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Result of my test.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using XElement...

```
    Dim path As String = "your path here"
    Dim xe As XElement
    ' xe = XElement.Load(path) 'Production

    ' for TESTING use literal.  Get rid of this for production
    xe = <configfile>

             <database_settings>
                 <databasename>peopledb</databasename>
                 <databaseuser>sa</databaseuser>
                 <databasepassword>verysecurepassword</databasepassword>
             </database_settings>

             <domain_admin_settings>
                 <username>myusername</username>
                 <password>verysecurepassword</password>
                 <domain>windowstest.local</domain>
             </domain_admin_settings>

         </configfile>

    Dim s As String = String.Format("Element name: {0}  Value: {1}",
                                        xe.<domain_admin_settings>.<username>.First.Name,
                                        xe.<domain_admin_settings>.<username>.Value)

    Console.WriteLine(s)
```

Production looks like this

```
    Dim path As String = "your path here"
    Dim xe As XElement
    xe = XElement.Load(path) 'Production

    Dim s As String = String.Format("Element name: {0}  Value: {1}",
                                        xe.<domain_admin_settings>.<username>.First.Name,
                                        xe.<domain_admin_settings>.<username>.Value)

    Console.WriteLine(s)
```